# Nuxt installs with depreciated version packages

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

I'm new to trying out NUXT and I have a newbie question I couldn't see answered anywhere online:

Why does create-nuxt-app install depreciated versions of packages?

I tried running npm update beforehand, but no effect.

```
> npm update
> npx create-nuxt-app gfgd_payment
npx: installed 379 in 24.753s
...
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy
 support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy
 support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy
 support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have choosed hapi during create project. And the latest **released** version of create-nuxt-app relies on old hapi version.

That was fixed in this PR -> https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/pull/231 but it wasnt yet released.

You could use latest version  of create nuxt app from repository via npx like this:

```
npx nuxt/create-nuxt-app
```